# deleting even nodes from a doubly link list c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete the nodes that are even in a doubly linked list by recursion. The problem is that it deletes the nodes but still show garbage in the deleted nodes space.

This is the output:

Here is the original list: 2 -> 2 -> 23 -> 2 -> 78 -> 5 -> 2

This list contains 7 number of items

The Number of even numbers is: 5

The number of even nodes removed was: 5

The resulting list is... 23 -> 5

***************After the even numbers are removed I get this back, Are you getting the same problem?***************************************

Now backwards: 5 -> **27303024** -> **27302960** -> 23 -> **27302928** -> **0**

This list contains 2 number of items

The sum of all data is: 28

```
int removeEven(node*& head) {
    // double pointer to use the address of pointer head
    node ** deleteNode = &head;
    //if is the end of the list stop
    if(head==NULL)
        return 0;
    //if is even
    if((*deleteNode) -> data %2==0)
    {
        node * helper = *deleteNode;
        *deleteNode = helper -> next;
        delete helper;

        return 1+ removeEven(helper -> next);
    }   
    //but if is an odd number
    else if ((*deleteNode) -> data %2)
    {
        //traverse to the next node
        deleteNode = &(*deleteNode)->next;
        //calls itself so that we can start againg to check in the new node.
        return removeEven(head -> next);
    }
}
```

I was told that changing the function like this will help but Im getting a lot of errors please help

---

```
//Remove even numbers
node* recfunremoveEven(node *head,node *prevnode, int* count) //helper function for remove even nodes
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(head->data %2 == 0) //data is even
    {
        *count+=1;
        free(head);
        node* next = recfunremoveEven(head->next,head,&count); //recursive call
        if(prevnode)
        {
            prevnode->next = next;
            next->previous = prevnode;
        }
        return next;
    }
    return recfunremoveEven(head->next,&count);
}

int removeEven(node*& head)
{
    int count=0;
    recfunremoveEven(head,&count);
    return count;
}
```

---

When compiling I get the following errors:

> g++ -g -std=c++11 -o proftest dlist.h dlist.cpp main.cpp supplied.o
>
> dlist.cpp: In function ‘node* recfunremoveEven(node*, node*, int*)’:
>
> dlist.cpp:30:53: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘int*’ for argument
>   ‘3’ to ‘node* recfunremoveEven(node*, node*, int*)’ node* next =
>   recfunremoveEven(head->next,head,&count); //recursive call ^
>
> dlist.cpp:38:42: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘node*’ for argument
>   ‘2’ to ‘node* recfunremoveEven(node*, node*, int*)’ return
>   recfunremoveEven(head->next,&count); ^
>
> dlist.cpp: In function ‘int removeEven(node*&)’: dlist.cpp:45:29:
>   error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘node*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘node*
>   recfunremoveEven(node*, node*, int*)’ recfunremoveEven(head,&count);

This is the .h file in case someone need to see it

```
//doubly linked list
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>


struct node
{
    int data;
    node * previous;
    node * next;
};

/* These functions are already written and can be called to test out your code */
void build(node * & head);  //supplied
void display(node * head);  //supplied
void destroy(node * &head); //supplied
//Recursively compute and return the number of nodes that contain even number
//in the doubly linked list
int countEven(node *head);
//Recursively remove all the nodes that contain even number in the doubly linked list
//and return the number of nodes removed 
int removeEven(node*& head);
```

Comment: yes I have been working on it for a lot of hours because tomorrow its my test and I want to be able to understand why is not working and learn from my mistakes so that Im prepare for my upcoming test and exercises

Comment: In your `removeEven` you do not touch `previous` pointer from `Node` which seems to be very suspicious...

Comment: would I be able to say for example in the case that the first node is even the set head->previous = head then move head and previous to the next node and set a temp pointer and delete the pointer but in the case that the even node is in the middle???

Comment: this is a past assignment Im here asking for help to learn no to do the assignment

Comment: can   you please provide an example so that I can have a more visual understanding of what you mean please

Comment: Make a drawing of your pointers, where they are now, and where you want them to be after the delete, then I think it will be quite clear what you should do.

Comment: uufff not working :(

Answer (score 0):

After `free(head)`, you're not allowed to dereference `head`, but you do.

You've also added some `&`s where you shouldn't (when recursing) and you left out a parameter on a couple of function calls.

But I think you're overcomplicating matters by passing around the "previous" node.

There are three cases to handle:

1. The list is empty,
2. The first node is odd,
3. The first node is even.

The first case is trivial.
The second and third are very similar:

- Remove the even nodes recursively from the rest of the list.
- Adjust the `previous` pointer of the result of that removal.
- If `head` is even, delete it and increment the count.
- Return either `head` (if it's odd) or the result of the recursion (if `head` was even).

I believe this should do it (beware - untested):

```
node* removeEvenWorker(node* head, int* count)
{
    // Case 1
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        *count = 0;
        return head;
    }

    // Recurse
    node* rest = removeEvenWorker(head->next, count);

    // Cases 2 & 3: Set up the first node.
    if (head->data % 2 != 0)
    {
        // Keep 'head'; link the recursive result to it.
        if (rest != nullptr)
        {
            rest->previous = head;
        }
        head->next = rest;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        // Discard 'head'
        if (rest != nullptr)
        {
            rest->previous = nullptr;
        }
        free(head);
        *count += 1;
        return rest;
    }

}
```

And calling it:

```
int removeEven(node*& head)
{
    int count = 0;
    head = removeEvenWorker(head, &count);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: dlist.cpp: In function ‘int removeEven(node*&)’:
dlist.cpp:25:35: error: too many arguments to function ‘int removeEven(node*&)’
     head = removeEven(head, &count);
                                   ^
dlist.cpp:22:5: note: declared here
 int removeEven(node*& head)
     ^
dlist.cpp:25:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘node*’ [-fpermissive]
     head = removeEven(head, &count);

Comment: Thanks for the reply why am i getting this erros I chnaged the remove_even for removeEven  because that was the way I had it but cant see why am I getting errors like this

Comment: please help me I want to be able to know why is it so hard to get this to work

Comment: @joshPradera It looks like you defined `int removeEven(node*&)` before `node* removeEven(node*, int*)` and forgot to add a prototype declaration. Either move the definitions around, or add the declaration `node* removeEven(node*, int*);` before the definition of the one-parameter function.

Comment: The error messages will become clearer if you give the functions different names. (I'll edit the answer.)

Comment: dlist.cpp: In function ‘int removeEven(node*&)’:
dlist.cpp:25:41: error: ‘removeEvenWorker’ was not declared in this scope
     head = removeEvenWorker(head, &count);

Comment: why would not be declared if it is ??

Comment: do I have to declare removeEvenWorkers in the .h file ?? if I do how do I put it like for example int or node* removeEvenWorker(node * head, int *count );

Comment: @joshPradera `removeEvenWorker` must be known before you can call it. Either define the functions in the same order as in this answer, or add the declaration `node* removeEvenWorker(node* head, int* count);` before the definition of `removeEven` (it should not be in a header since it's only supposed to be used by `removeEven`).

Comment: Ok I wish to explain how happy I am at this moment this world needs more people like that help other I will do my best to help others too, Thanks SOOOOOOO much lol you dont know how long I have been researching why was this not working hahahaha