# Recursively Delete Even Items from Doubly Linked List C++

Tags: c++, recursion, gdb

Here is the same question I am asking:
[deleting even nodes from a doubly link list c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721465/deleting-even-nodes-from-a-doubly-link-list-c)

The difference is, I want to understand what is wrong with my code. I don't want to have to just accept a completely different approach without understand why my code doesn't work. Here are two versions of my code I would like to know what is wrong with both. Both of them give me segmentation fault.

```
int removeEven(node *&head)
{
if(!head)               //Base case: end of list reached
    return 0;
int count = removeEven(head->next);     //Recurse to end of list
if(head->data % 2 != 0)
    return count;
else{
    ++count;
    if(head->next){
        head->next->previous = head->previous;
    }
    if(head->previous){
        head->previous->next = head->next;
    } if(!(head->previous)){
        node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
        delete head;
}
return count;
}
```

This second one takes count = 0 as a default arg.

```
int removeEven(node *&head, int count)
if(head && head->data % 2 != 0) //not null, not even
{
    removeEven(head->next, count);
}
else if(head != NULL){      //not null, yes even
   ++count;
    if(head->next)
        head->next->previous = head->previous;
    if(head->previous)
        head->previous->next = head->next;
    node* temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
   removeEven(head, count);
}
    return count;       //base case: null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int removeEven(node *&head)
{
  if(!head)               //Base case: end of list reached
    return 0;
  int count = removeEven(head->next);     //Recurse to end of list
  if(head->data % 2 != 0)
    return count;
  else{
    ++count;
    // CORRECT WAY!!! copy the old pointer in a temp
    node *t = head;
    if(head->next){
      head->next->previous = head->previous;
    }
    if(head->previous){
      // WARNING!!! here you are ACTUALLY modifying head to nullptr
      head->previous->next = head->next;
    }
    // CORRECT WAY!!! delete the temp pointer
    delete t;
    // WARNING!!! here you are trying to access a nullptr in head
    // if(!(head->previous)){
    //   node* temp = head;
    //   head = head->next;
    //   delete temp;
    // }
    // else
    //   delete head;
  }
  return count;
}
```

I have got the hint of the root cause by valgrind and gdb

```
valgrind ./a.out 
==2729== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2729== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2729== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2729== Command: ./a.out
==2729== 
[9] [8] [7] [6] [5] [4] [3] [2] [1] [0] 
==2729== Invalid read of size 8
==2729==    at 0x4008F5: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:26)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x400AFD: main (list1.cpp:81)
==2729==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2729== 
==2729== 
==2729== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2729==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==2729==    at 0x4008F5: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:26)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x40087A: removeEven(node*&) (list1.cpp:15)
==2729==    by 0x400AFD: main (list1.cpp:81)
==2729==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2729==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2729==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2729==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2729==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8720384.
==2729== 
==2729== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2729==     in use at exit: 240 bytes in 10 blocks
==2729==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 0 frees, 240 bytes allocated
==2729== 
==2729== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2729==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==2729==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2729==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2729==    still reachable: 216 bytes in 9 blocks
==2729==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2729== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2729== 
==2729== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2729== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Compilation segmentation fault at Fri Jul 28 09:46:51
```

Comment: Please see the comments about the error and also the correct way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately it still isn't working. It says error in ./main double free or corruption and gives me a backtrace and memory map. GDB gives SIGABRT

Comment: And, I don't understand what is the difference here:
    node *t = head;
    if(head->next)
      head->next->previous = head->previous;
    if(head->previous)
      head->previous->next = head->next;
    delete t;
How is deleting t any different than deleting head? Head was not modified after you assigned t = head.

Comment: Inside the if(head->previous) statement lets consider when head is the last element. In that case head->next = nullptr, and head->previous->next is actually head itself. so by this assignment head->previous->next = head->next; you are assigning nullptr to head. in the next expression head->previous you trying to access a nullptr and getting a valid segmentation fault.

Comment: The complete program source code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17e5e840a391b263

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, I do see that now. But, this still won't work and I don't think I can do anything about it. My professor wrote the rest of the program, which I cannot see. I just had to write this function on a test. It still won't work after copying your code exactly.

Comment: I used the solution code provided from the original poster's question, and that works just fine. So, there still must be something wrong with the code we have here.

Comment: I tested your code with a list beginning with an even item, and it fails. All the test cases the professor provides begin with an even item.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with a list beginning with an even item, and it fails. All the test cases the professor provides begin with an even item.
Here is the solution:

```
int removeEven(node *&head)
{
if(!head)               //Base case: end of list reached
    return 0;
int count = removeEven(head->next);     //Recurse to end of list
if(head->data % 2 != 0)
    return count;
else{
    ++count;
    node *t = head;
    if(head->next)
        head->next->previous = head->previous;
    if(head->previous)
        head->previous->next = head->next;
    if(head && !head->previous)
        head = head->next;
    delete t;
}
return count;
}
```

The issue was the actual original head pointer would get lost if the head node was deleted. Now I check to see if we are at the actual head because head->previous should be NULL, and then I set the actual head pointer to the next node in the list before deleting.